# 3D graphics for multiple platforms using Intel XDK

Tags: mobile, 3d, intel-xdk

I am developing an app using Intel XDK and Angularjs. I want the app to be available on as many platforms as possible including Android, iOS, and Windows. I also want interactive 3D graphics in my app. Is it possible to have all of this?

I have looked into the App Gaming Interface (AGI) that comes with Intel XDK but it uses 2D graphics.

I have also looked into Marmalade Web but I did not see any documentation, tutorials, or examples that display interactive 3D graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to investigate the use of some game engines to provide your 3D graphics. You are probably going to need WebGL to get respectable performance and the 3D graphics you need. That means you will be limited to only the newest devices.

On Android you can use the Crosswalk build system and it will include a runtime that includes a very capable WebGL subsystem that will work on Android 4.x (and above) devices. For other systems you must work with the WebView that is provided on the target (the embedded browser cannot be replaced). Thus, you will be restricted to iOS 8 and Windows 8.1 Phone devices.

The App Gaming Interface in the XDK has been officially deprecated and is not being further developed. This is due to the excellent support for canvas and WebGL in Crosswalk for Android and the new support for WebGL and improved JavaScript performance in the new WKWebView that is part of iOS 8.